# Use FunctionQuery idf on actual value of a Field

Tags: solr, solr4

I have a Solr Index containing some products *(Desc, ImageUrl & qty)*. The default search field is **Desc** *(i.e. the Description)*, though the other fields are stored and indexed. I would like to boost products that have more ***unique images*** *(i.e. unique values of the **ImageUrl** – which is basically a GUID path to the image binary)*. By this I mean a product whose image only occurs 2 times would get a boost over another product whose image occurs 5 times.

I think the [Function Query idf](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#idf)   would be the most appropriate, but it needs me to specify the *Term* i.e. it is defined as ***idf(field,term)***, but I would like the second parameter to be the *Field* value instead. I attempted the following but I get a NullPointerException:

```
&bf=idf(ImageUrl,field(ImageUrl))
```

I realize that this is because ***field()*** always tries to evaluate to a numeric value and it fails. Anyway way to get the value of the field.

I can say that a boost function like:

```
&bf=log(qty)
```

works perfectly i.e. the **&bf** part seems correct.

I'd appreciate what I should try. I am running Solr 4.9.

**Edit:** As requested below, I am adding the schema for the `ImageUrl` field:

```
<field name="ImageUrl" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Comment: `ImageUrl` is multivalued, correct? If not, please provide a schema configuration. Also `boost products that have more unique images` and `By this I mean a product whose image only occurs 2 times would get a boost over another product whose image occurs 5 times.`... shouldn't the **attempted bf** boost the product with 5  matches over the product with 2 ?

Comment: Thank you **rchukh**. `ImageUrl` is single valued. I would like products with generic images to rank lower.